# How to use the cloth brush without restriction?

Tags: sculpting, cloth-simulation

After starting to brush (left mouseclick) I'm only able to use it in a certain circle (marked yellow). None of the tutorials display that behaviour. How can I overcome this and use the brush everywhere?

[image: pic]

Comment: Press F then move the mouse left or right to increase or decrease the radius of influence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sculpt out of the limits of this yellow circle (which will appear red actually). It is called the *Simulation Limit* and it's not the same as the brush *Radius*: When you left click on the object you want to sculpt, the position of the cursor determines the location of this area. As long as you won't release the left click you won't be able to sculpt out of this area.

To make this area bigger you can either increase the radius of your brush (<kbd>F</kbd>) or in the *N panel > Tool > Brush Settings > Simulation Limit*. In the latter case it's not the brush that is bigger, but the *Simulation Limit* relatively to the brush size:

[image]